# Android Studio не отображает темы

Tags: android-studio

Создал новый проект, решил покопаться в Material Design, ну и после выбора Material Dark, она перестала отображать часть Activity (кроме ActionBar). Так она не отображает все темы что я выбираю. Почему - непонятно. Выбирал минимальную API14, манифест и gradle-файлы не трогал пока. В чем проблема ?
![скриншотстудии]https://pp.userapi.com/c638530/v638530145/52f73/6a6AUsejiBU.jpg

Comment: Смотри ошибки рендаренга, собственно из-за них это и происходит

Comment: ![скрин манифеста]https://pp.userapi.com/c638530/v638530662/6e325/KSZ_jNBT508.jpg

Comment: Добавил в тему activity в манифесте Theme.AppCompat (как и требовала студия) в итоге приложение не загружается на физ. устройстве пока выбран Theme.AppCompat

Comment: Решение найдено, благодарю за коммент.

Comment: @CthulhuRlyeh Пожалуйста. Если сам разобрался, напиши свой ответ хотя бы в двух словах. Что бы те, у кого будет похожая проблема знали что делать.

Comment: Крч нужно просто добавить наследник AppCompat  в проект, с помощью него тема запуститься должна